# Failed to successfully execute the ODCIIndexCreate routine. - Oracle Spatial Indexing

Tags: oracle, indexing, spatial

I have two oracle spatial tables, namely, `restaurants` and `persons`. The structures of these two tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE restaurants(
 id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
 name VARCHAR2(32),
 shape SDO_GEOMETRY
);

CREATE TABLE persons(
 p_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
 p_name VARCHAR2(32),
 p_shape SDO_GEOMETRY
);
```

Then, after populating each table I wanted to create spatial index for each table. The following instruction for `restaurants` table executed successfully.

```
CREATE INDEX restaurants_spatial_idx
ON restaurants(shape)
INDEXTYPE IS mdsys.spatial_index;
```

But, when I wrote for `persons` table:

```
CREATE INDEX persons_spatial_idx
ON persons(p_shape)
INDEXTYPE IS mdsys.spatial_index;
```

This gave me the following error in sql developer 3.2.20:

**Error starting at line 340 in command:**

**CREATE INDEX persons_spatial_idx**

**ON persons(p_shape)**

**INDEXTYPE IS mdsys.spatial_index**

**Error at Command Line:340 Column:14**

**Error report:**
**SQL Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"**

**Cause:

Action:**

As this was saying that I have already and index named `persons_spatial_idx`, I deleted this index using: `DROP INDEX persons_spatial_idx;` Then when I tried to create the index again, it produced the following error:

Error starting at line 340 in command:

CREATE INDEX persons_spatial_idx
    ON persons(p_shape)
    INDEXTYPE IS mdsys.spatial_index

Error at Command Line:340 Column:14

Error report:

SQL Error: ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine

ORA-13249: internal error in Spatial index: [mdidxrbd]

ORA-13249: Error in Spatial index: index build failed

ORA-13249: Error in spatial index: [mdrcrtxfergm]

ORA-13249: Error in spatial index: [mdpridxtxfergm]

ORA-13200: internal error [ROWID:AAAFGnAABAAALHpAAA] in spatial indexing.

ORA-13206: internal error [] while creating the spatial index

ORA-13365: layer SRID does not match geometry SRID

ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I", line 10

29855. 00000 -  "error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine"

*Cause:    Failed to successfully execute the ODCIIndexCreate routine.

*Action:   Check to see if the routine has been coded correctly.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The message is clear enough: it's saying that you already have an object named PERSONS_SPATIAL_IDX. What's the problem with that?

Comment: Yes, when I see the index table, I see an entry for PERSONS_SPATIAL_IDX. Then I deleted each entry from the index table. Then, I ran it again. But it gives me same error.

Comment: What you mean with "deleted the entry?" Did you `DROP` the existing index?

Comment: I used this to delete `DROP INDEX persons_spatial_idx;`

Comment: Please EDIT YOUR QUESTION and include all information pertaining to the question in the question itself. Thanks.

Comment: Then I got a different error:  **Error starting at line 340 in command: CREATE INDEX persons_spatial_idx ON persons(p_shape) INDEXTYPE IS mdsys.spatial_index Error at Command Line:340 Column:14 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine ..... ..... *Cause: Failed to successfully execute the ODCIIndexCreate routine. *Action: Check to see if the routine has been coded correctly.**

Comment: So you have a different question. Please edit the question to clearly describe your actual problem or, better, open a new question for the new issue you are having.

Comment: I have edited it to the extent now.

Answer (score 0):

The message is saying that an object with name `PERSONS_SPATIAL_IDX` already exists.
You can use the following query to find the existing index:

```
select *
from all_indexes
where index_name = 'PERSONS_SPATIAL_IDX'
```

Comment: Yes, I saw it was there. Then I dropped it by `DROP INDEX persons_spatial_idx;`. Then I tried to re-run the instruction, but this time I got a different error:

**Error starting at line 340 in command:
CREATE INDEX persons_spatial_idx
    ON persons(p_shape)
    INDEXTYPE IS mdsys.spatial_index
Error at Command Line:340 Column:14
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
.....
.....
*Cause:    Failed to successfully execute the ODCIIndexCreate routine.
*Action:   Check to see if the routine has been coded correctly.**

Answer (score 0):

For any one who has encountered this type of error in Oracle SQL I sorta found a work around by modifying the meta-data of GEOM_METADATA. **Changing the SRID to NULL in the table `ALL_SDO_GEOM_METADATA` for the table where the geometry is located then the index is created successfully**.

**! This is probably not a good solution and I do not know the full implications of changing the SRID to NULL !**